# How can I retrieve code from Heroku which was deployed using a 'Deploy to Heroku' button

Tags: git, heroku

Usually you can retrieve code for a Heroku app using the `heroku git:clone` command. If the app was deployed using a Heroku 'Deploy to Heroku' button then cloning results in an empty repo (see [here](https://help.heroku.com/XOBUHLKQ/why-do-i-see-a-message-you-appear-to-have-cloned-an-empty-repository-when-using-heroku-git-clone) for details).

The method to retrieve the code described in the link above assumes that the original repo still exists.

How would I retrieve the code if the original repo no longer exists?

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this I used the following command:

`mkdir -p {app name} && heroku run "tar -cz * | base64 -w 0" --app {app name} | base64 -D | tar -xzf - -C {app name}`

This was from bash in MacOS so some of the local bash command parameters may be different in other flavours of Unix.

Depending on your app you may need to exclude some directories in the `tar -cz` command (e.g. `--exclude='./node_modules'`)

Answer (score 0):

You can `heroku run bash` and manually copy over the code.

Comment: Sorry armatav, was posting the question so I could answer it as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). I didn't realise you can submit the question and answer at the same time.